# How to transform C program into classes

Tags: c++, c, arrays, class, recursion

so I've been working on this program and its objective was to use recursion and an adjacency matrix to find how many possible routes a person could take to get through a subway system without going over a track more than once. That was self explanatory for me but now I'm lost on program 2 which is to do the same problem from program 1 in C++ and using three classes and recursion. The classes are suppose to be SubwaySystem, Station, and Track. I don't really know how to go about the transition from a simple adjacency matrix into three classes? It seems counterproductive since it seems more complicated. I have been working on it for a while know and I can't seem to utilize all three classes.

What I have tried: My approach was I created 1 Subway System with 12 Stations, and each station with an array of Tracks. For example, Station A has one station it can go to which is B. In Station A there is an array of 12 tracks but only 1 track is activated. However I keep running to errors since I tried to initialize the arrays in the Track class and then use them in the SubwaySystem class. Then trying to use recursion to get all possible routes makes it that much more difficult. I really don't know how to figure this out.

The adjacency matrix in the my code pretty much maps out the entire connection from station to station. The station are A - L corresponding to each row/column. I don't know how to represent this in c++ **without** using an adjacency matrix.

My code in C (program 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void routesFinder(int row, int col);

char station[13] = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
char order[25] = "A";
int subway[12][12] = {{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                 {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                 {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                 {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                 {0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                 {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                 {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}};

int paths = 0, i = 1;

int main(){
     routesFinder(0, 0); //start with first station row, first column
     printf("\n%d days before repeating a route.\n", paths);
     return 0;
}

void routesFinder(int row, int col) {
     while (col < 12) { //go through columns of a row
         if (subway[row][col] == 0) { // if no station is found in row
            if (row == 11) { // station found
               paths++;
               printf("Route %d: %s.\n", paths, order);
               return;
            }
            col++;
            if (row != 11 && col == 12) { //backtracking from deadend
               return;
            }
         }
         if (subway[row][col] == 1) {
            order[i] = station[col]; //add station to route
            i++; //increment, prepare for next route
            subway[row][col] = 0; //no track forward
            subway[col][row] = 0; // or backward
            routesFinder(col, 0); //recursion, look for path in new row
            order[i] = '\0'; //remove route
            i--; //decrement, prepare for next route
            subway[row][col] = 1; //restore path
            subway[col][row] = 1; // restore path
            col++; //returning from deadend, check for next open path
            if (row != 11 && col == 12) { //return from deadend
                return;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You want to use a graph,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure), one with nodes and edges rather than an adjacency matrix. Stations are your nodes, tracks are your edges, SubwaySystem is your entire graph. Once you are done, you may find the node/edge implementation cleaner than the adjacency matrix.

Comment: There are many viable solutions. Why isn't one chosen?

Answer (score 2):

In general I can tell you that in c++ in particular and in object oriented in general,
each object should have its unique role in the system. Each is encapsulating a behavior and a knowledge that are its own and sole responsibility.
As for you specific problem - Without getting too deeply into the problem, I think the idea would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Track;
typedef std::vector<Track*> TrackList;

class Station
{

    public:
        Station( std::string name ) : _name( name ){};
        ~Station(){}

    public:
        const std::string& GetName() const
        { return _name; }

        TrackList& GetTrackList()  
        { return _trackList; }

        void AddTrack( Track& track )
        { _trackList.push_back( &track );  }

    private:
        std::string _name;
        TrackList _trackList;
};

class Track
{
    public:
        Track( Station& edgeA, Station& edgeB )
            : 
                _edgeA( edgeA ),
                _edgeB( edgeB ),
                _wasVisited( false )
        { 
            edgeA.AddTrack( *this );
            edgeB.AddTrack( *this );
        }
        ~Track(){}

    public:
        bool WasVisited() const
        { return _wasVisited; }

        void SetVisited()
        { _wasVisited = true; }

    public:
        Station& GetEdgeA()
        { return _edgeA; }

        Station& GetEdgeB()
        { return _edgeB; }

    private:
        Station& _edgeA;
        Station& _edgeB;
        bool _wasVisited;
};

class SubwaySystem
{
    public:
        SubwaySystem() {}
        ~SubwaySystem() {}

    public:
       void Traverse( Station& start )
       {
           TrackList& tracks = start.GetTrackList();
           TrackList::iterator it = tracks.begin();

           while ( it != tracks.end() )
           {
               if ( ! (*it)->WasVisited() )
               {
                   std::cout << (*it)->GetEdgeA().GetName() << "-->" << (*it)->GetEdgeB().GetName() << ",";
                   (*it)->SetVisited();
                   Traverse( (*it)->GetEdgeB() ); 
               } 

               ++ it;
           } 
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }

};

int main()
{
    Station A( "A" );
    Station B( "B" );
    Station C( "C" );
    Station D( "D" );
    Station E( "E" );

    Track AB( A, B );
    Track BC( B, C );
    Track CA( C, A );
    Track CD( C, D );
    Track CE( C, E );
    Track AE( A, E );


    SubwaySystem subway;
    subway.Traverse( A ); 
}
```

The output to this is

```
A-->B,B-->C,C-->A,A-->E,C-->E,


C-->D,
```

Surly you can 'play' with the Traverse function and put the printings in other places,
select another end-recursion condition, etc.

Notice how clean main() is.
You just declare the Stations and the Tracks and the voodoo happens.
Adding more tracks is simple, just describe the link and that's all, the track wad 'added' to the subway.

Other parts of the applications are also very clean, as each class knows exactly what it should and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would to have the subway system hold control over all the stations. The stations would then have tracks that knew the origin (which station they came from) and the destination (which station they could go to).

The adjacency matrix would be broken up, the whole thing is represented inside the subway system, each row/column is represented in the stations, and each 1/0 is represented by the tracks. There would be no track for a zero.

Which paths to take would be decided at the station level, with which tracks being used/destinations already have been gone to. The tracks could have a property that keep track if they have been ridden on.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing. The question I have is if I put the tracks within the stations themselves, how do I utilize the track class. Would the individual tracks be initialized in the track class then passed to the stations? (I think that would cause a lot of bugs at least it did a while ago when I attempted to do it that way.)

Comment: The purpose of each track (each station would have an array or vector or whatever), is to keep track of each segment of the trip, (from where, to where) and if it has been used. (also, no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this in C, you might have structures like this

```
typedef struct node node; 
typedef struct edge edge;
typedef struct graph graph;

struct graph { // subway system
    node *nodes; // stations
};
struct node { // station 
    char *name;
    edge *edges; // tracks connected to this station
    node *next; // next node in graph
    bool visited;
}
struct edge { // track
   node *src;  // from station
   node *dst;  // to station
   edge *next; // next track, this station
   bool visited; 
}
```

Transforming that into classes should be easy. Except that they might want you to use stl data structures instead of simply inlining the lists like I did.

The simple recursive graph algorithms map nicely to these data structures.

Comment: For each 1 in the adjacency matrix you add an edge from one station to the other. Google "Depth-first search"

Comment: To convert to C++ classes, just compile with a C++ compiler. struct declares classes in C++ (with default public for all members).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of recursion for counting is a little hard to get, but let me try to explain at least that part.

So you know how strlen works, in C, right?  You walk the array and keep a count.  But here's a recursive version

```
unsigned int strlen(const char * string) {
  if (*string == '\0') { return 0; }
  else return 1 + strlen(string + 1);
}
```

Do you see how that works?  Not that useful when walking an array where you can use a simple counter, but when you are dealing with issues where there are multiple possible combinations of doing things, or multiple ways of going, it works nicely. For example, if you wanted to count the number of nodes in a binary tree, you might do something like.

```
unsigned int treecount(NODE * node) {
    if (node == NULL) { return 0;}
    else return 1 + treecount(node->left) + treecount(node->right);
}
```

Hopefully that helps.  Charlie Burns is probably right that doing it with a graph is a good idea.